# How can I make serverless to reference a lambda layer automatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a lambda application using `serverless` to deploy. The structure is shown as below:

```
apps/
apps/package.json
apps/serverless.yml

layers
layers/package.json
layers/serverless.yml
```

There are two folders `apps` and `layers`. In the `layers`, it defines the lambda layer infra. And in `apps`, it is the application code. I usually go to `layers` folder then run `serverless deploy` command which gives me the layer ARN. Then I paste the ARN to `apps/serverless.yml` manually. I am looking for a pattern which can take the layer ARN automatically. How can I do that in serverless?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the layer output and reference the output in the app serverless.yml

My layer serverless.yml

```
service: gt-layers
layers:
  ffmpeg:
    path: layer

resources:
  Outputs:
    FfmpegLayerExport:
        Value:
          Ref: FfmpegLambdaLayer
        Export:
          Name: FfmpegLambdaLayer
```

My App serverless.yml

```
  video_upload_notification:
    handler: handler.video_upload_notification
    layers:
      - ${cf:gt-layers-${self:provider.stage}.FfmpegLayerExport}
```

You can refer the blog [here](https://www.serverless.com/blog/publish-aws-lambda-layers-serverless-framework/)

Comment: Don't forget to provide your `provider.stackName` (in this example it seems to be:
`${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}`